# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo, app crashes

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

When I run this code the app crashes and I get an "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo" error, and I noticed that this happens when I initialize the cursor.
Here is the method thar returns a Cursor in my DBadapter class:

```
public Cursor getAllQuestionsParNiveau(String niveau){

    String sql = "SELECT designQuestion FROM Question, Quiz, Question_Quiz " +
            "WHERE Question.idQuestion = Question_Quiz.idQuestion " +
            "AND Quiz.idQuiz = Question_Quiz.idQuiz " +
            "AND Quiz.niveauQuiz = '" + niveau + "'";

    return db.rawQuery(sql, null);
}
```

This is the activity where I call the method:

```
package com.example.quiz;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Quizz extends Activity {

private ArrayList<String> listQuestions = new ArrayList<String>();

private DBAdapter adapter;
private Cursor cursor;
private Button suivant;
private Button precedent;
private TextView question;
private int i = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quizz);

    suivant = (Button)findViewById(R.id.suivant);
    precedent = (Button)findViewById(R.id.precedent);
    question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);

    try{
        cursor = adapter.getAllQuestionsParNiveau("Débutant");
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            listQuestions.add(cursor.getString(0));
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException se){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Erreur !\n" + se.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //question.setText(listQuestions.get(0));
    question.setText("hahahaha");

    /*suivant.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i = i+1;
            question.setText(listQuestions.get(i));
        }
    });

    precedent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i = i-1;
            question.setText(listQuestions.get(i));
        }
    });*/
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quizz, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And this is the log:

```
04-07 15:32:06.973: E/Trace(2001): error opening trace file: No such file or   directory (2)
04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001): java.lang.RuntimeException:     Unable to instantiate activity    ComponentInfo{com.example.quiz/com.example.quiz.Quizz}:    java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at com.example.quiz.Quizz. <init>(Quizz.java:21)
04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001): at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
```

04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
    04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054) 
    04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
    04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     ... 11 more

Comment: What is line 21 of Quizz ? On a side note, its not a good idea to do any database operation on the main/UI thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is actually this:

```
 04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 04-07 15:32:41.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2001):     at com.example.quiz.Quizz. <init>(Quizz.java:21)
```

I suspect that's somewhere in the beginning of your `onCreate()` method - either when initialising the views or more likely `cursor = adapter.getAllQuestionsParNiveau("Débutant");`. I don't see where the adapter is initialised ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not initializing the cursor adapter. This is what's causing your null pointer exception.

You're declaring your DBadapter as adapter, but you're not actually initializing it. So when you call adapter.whatever, you're getting nothing.